Extracting multi agent RL patterns from AST representation
I have an AST representation of a multi agent reinforcement learning algo. I am trying to extract certain instances of code which tell us it is a multi agent representation. Some of them are:

I want to traverse the FunctionDef, look for the  init, traverse through the args then check if any args named n_agents are present
I need to look for train loop definitions, such as

def train(self):
    for agent_id in range(self.n_agents)

self.actor_optimizers[agent_id].zero_grad()
self.critic_optimizers[agent_id].zero_grad()

which imply that the actor and critic networks are getting updated separately.

need to traverse the softmax function to detect the loop where the probabilities of each agent are getting calculated separately. In the code it would be this line under def _softmax_actionfunction

for agent_id in range(self.n_agents):
   softmax_action_var = th.exp(self.actors[agent_id](state_var[:,agent_id,:]))


The output would be something like this:



Practice
Instance
Definition




Multiple agent instantiation
n_agents
Multiple agents present in the environment.


Actor-critic instantiation
def train(self):    for agent_id in range(self.n_agents):        self.actor_optimizers[agent_id].zero_grad()        self.critic_optimizers[agent_id].zero_grad()
Method train() loops over each agent (for agent_id in range(self.n_agents)) to update the actor and critic networks separately. Zeroes gradients for the actor and critic networks of each agent.


Softmax function
for agent_id in range(self.n_agents):    softmax_action_var = th.exp(self.actors[agent_id](state_var[:,agent_id,:]))
Loop over each agent present to compute softmax probabilities separately.



Getting these parameters from the code directly is not so difficult, but I am a bit lost as to how to do this through the AST representation. It would be great if any of you could give me some help/suggestions with this.

How are you accessing the AST representation? Are you reading it in from a file? How do you have it represented in memory - As a list of lines of text, or something more structured?

I am accessing my ast from a txt file. I just parse the python file using ast and the result is stored in a txt file

Hello Brie, sry, what exactly is the question? 1. You are not sure how to start parsing AST file? Could you please provide the code that you have as of now? 2. Or you don't know how to read AST files? If this is the case you can search for known functions or variable names (for example for agent_id), find them in AST file and start reverse engineering AST syntax from this.

actually there exists a python library to achieve exactly what you need: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html
